# How to execute SSRS 2012 report using stored credentials?

Tags: reporting-services, active-directory

I'm trying to configure the data source for an SSRS 2012 report using the "Credentials stored securely in the report server" option. I specified an AD ID and password, and checked the "Use as Windows Credentials when connecting to the data source" option. I click the Test Connection button and I get "Login failed for user ad1\myuserid". I know the password is correct since I am using it for other things. The MSDN doc on this says it should work.

Does anyone else use an AD ID and password with stored credentials for SSRS 2012? Is there a trick to it?

Comment: So after about another hour of searching I stumbled on an article stating that the ID requires "Log on Locally" privileges. I sent the info to the server admins and will hopefully get to test this afternoon. Thanks for the downvote :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the "log on locally" post was incorrect. You simply need to select the option to use credentials stored on the reporting server, provide the credentials, then check the "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source" option. Test the connection, Apply the change and you're all set.